# How to have one row only to capture the information of those 3 columns?

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 columns each one with a type of information I need to view in only one row. Happens that each one of the values of those columns are being displayed in different rows..how to avoid that?

Here is my code.

```
SELECT     ReportViews.LicenseReferenceCodes.[Reference Code Type], ReportViews.LicenseReferenceCodes.[Reference Code], ReportViews.Licenses.[Official Area], 
                      ReportViews.Licenses.[License Code]
FROM         ReportViews.Licenses INNER JOIN
                      ReportViews.LicenseReferenceCodes ON ReportViews.LicenseReferenceCodes.idLicense = ReportViews.Licenses.idLicense
GROUP BY ReportViews.LicenseReferenceCodes.[Reference Code Type], ReportViews.LicenseReferenceCodes.[Reference Code], ReportViews.Licenses.[Official Area], 
                      ReportViews.Licenses.[License Code]
HAVING      (ReportViews.LicenseReferenceCodes.[Reference Code Type] = N'CCIR') OR
                      (ReportViews.LicenseReferenceCodes.[Reference Code Type] = N'CAR') OR
                      (ReportViews.LicenseReferenceCodes.[Reference Code Type] = N'NIRF')
ORDER BY ReportViews.Licenses.[License Code]
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you try to group it by? It looks as you have not tried anything yet.

Comment: I don't know nothing about SQL queries...a friend of mine designed this code for me...I have tried GROUP BY but keeps getting this message "Unable to parse query text."

Comment: I would advise you to check the MSDN then. Stackoverflow is not the place to ask this question. You need to do somewhat of a research to start with then if you still cant get it right, you are welcome to ask.

Comment: You should read up about aliases too. Not only does it turn this wall of text into something you can actually read it avoids problems in the future because Table.Schema.Column has been deprecated in the select list

Comment: For future use "code" format for code snippets to make it more readable for people who is willing to answer it.

Comment: All right guys...I shouldn't have asked this question before reading some more about this forum...I don't have any idea of what this code is doing or making...as I said a friend of mine designed it for me but I'm having issues like I said on the post and I don't have the minor idea on how to fix it. Anyway thanks for the tips about posting here. Admin can close/delete this post if it's inappropriate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to close your question you just need to help us understand what you want. As I suggested in my comment about aliases here is what you query would look like with some formatting.

```
SELECT lrc.[Reference Code Type]
    , lrc.[Reference Code]
    , l.[Official Area]
    , l.[License Code]
FROM ReportViews.Licenses l
INNER JOIN ReportViews.LicenseReferenceCodes lrc ON lrc.idLicense = l.idLicense
GROUP BY lrc.[Reference Code Type]
    , lrc[Reference Code]
    , l.[Official Area]
    , l.[License Code]
HAVING lrc[Reference Code Type] in (N'CCIR', N'CAR', N'NIRF')
ORDER BY l.[License Code]
```

Now that we have a legible query to work with, what is the issue you are having? What we would want to see is ddl and sample data for those two tables along with what you want as output from the sample data. Here is an excellent post explaining how to capture this information. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/